# In a POSIX environment, how do I track files accessed by a child process?

Tags: file, monitoring, posix

I have my own POSIX application which starts a child process. I want the parent process to be notified with the names of all files the child process reads or writes, as well as the file names of any child processes the child spawns, and any dynamic libraries it loads. Similarly, I need to monitor all child processes spawned by child processes, etc.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas for this.

**Method 1** - The "real way".

I think you want [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace).  But it isn't going to be easy to use.

Essentially this call is for writing a debugger.  Note that `PTRACE_SYSCALL` steps until the next syscall.  At which point you might be able to use more `ptrace` calls to peek at the process's memory to observe if it's, say, a call to `open()`.

**Method 2** - The lazy, hackish way.

You could use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.  That is, write a shared library with your own implementation of the calls you want to hook (say, `open()`, `dlopen()`), adding your own code and dispatching to the normal libc version.  Then you point the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable at this shared library so the dynamic linker will load it at process start.

One downside to this approach is that if a process knows it's being observed this way, it can reset the environment variable and execute itself again, and evade detection.  Another I can think of is that as a security feature this environment variable is not honored if you're root.